# wrong behavior with :hover

Tags: html, css

When you hover over the area `<li>` it becomes red, but the area inside the `<a>` remains white. Area `<a>` turns red when I point at her. This happens separately.

How to fix this?   How to make the hover area `<li>` the entire field had turned red?

```css
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu * {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  background: #e50003;
}
.menu ul li.active > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e50003;
}
.menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
.menu ul li:hover > .submenu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
      <div class="submenu submenu1">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.menu *` is setting the `a` to have a white background. The `li:hover` won't change that until you hover it too. Consider just using `.menu` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove those:

```
.menu * {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e50003;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu * {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  background: #e50003;
}
.menu ul li.active > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e50003;
}*/
.menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
.menu ul li:hover > .submenu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
      <div class="submenu submenu1">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be caused by my PC.

Comment: you see the same result as the question? try to clean your cache

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: If submenu > 2, we get the effect of breadcrumbs in the menu(all selections remain red at the previous levels of the menu). Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `child` element's background while hovering on `parent` element, which is in your case.

```
.menu ul li:hover,
.menu ul li:hover > a{
  background: #e50003;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu * {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li:hover,
.menu ul li:hover > a{
  background: #e50003;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li.active > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bbb;
  
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.05s;
}
.menu ul li:hover > .submenu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
      <div class="submenu submenu1">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Can you tell me the reason of downvote?

Comment: The problem was a wrong piece of code, he doesn't need to fix, just to cut

Comment: Learn how to use downvotes, my answers is just a different approach not a bad or wrong answer.

Comment: it is, giving him a way to do something with 100 lines of code is better than doing it with 200. Giving him another answer with lower performances when there a better answer, just not make any sense

Comment: Downvotes are for wrong answers not for less good answers, if your answer is better than the others, sit back and relax your answer will automatically get upvotes, and stop downvoting other answers to prove yours as best.

Comment: i never do it, it's the first time couse i think it's just wrong ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu ul li.active > a:hover,
.menu ul li.active > a
{
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above you got the right answer.
Just to tag, looks like there is an enhancement to make the width of Red part is changing once hovering.
Change is width should be 220px under .menu like below.

```
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```